# Splits in tmux keeping same directory and same file opened

Tags: vim, tmux

I use tmux and vim at the same time. To do splits I prefer to do them in tmux. The only problem is that when I create a split, the new panel opens in the root folder. First, I have to navigate to the subfolder where I was working and then open the corresponding vim file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: vim is designed to do splits on the current file (and session). Doing a split in tmux, then having two different vim processes running on the same file seems like you are trying to work against the designed flow. Is there an issue starting tmux, then vim and doing the split in vim?

Comment: The reason is that I am more familiar with the movement between panels in tmux. Some time ago, I decided to avoid mixing splits, because I always ended up mixing tmux commands in vim and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [vim-tmux-navigator](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator) plugin make the same movements work for tmux and vim splits. I have it set up so that ctrl+j/k/h/l moves between tmux and vim splits. Now it feels 100% natural.

Having multiple files open in one vim session allows you to use all of vim's yanking/pasting operations to move copy/move text between files. In my opinion this is a huge benefit of running a single vim instance, one that outweighs the time to get into the habit of configuring/learning some keys to navigate tmux/vim splits.